# R Adding a column to a data frame based on atomic vector data

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to add a column to my data frame that will be named Solvent and will either return yes or no based on solvent utilization, I've successfully added one other column that gets the county data but my code for solvent isn't working. I receive the error:  "Error in SCC$SCC.Level.One : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

```
    NEI <- readRDS("summarySCC_PM25.rds")
SCC <- readRDS("Source_Classification_Code.rds")

library(ggplot2)


form <- NEI[,c("fips","SCC", "Emissions")]
LANEI <- form[form$fips=="06037",]
OCNEI <- form[form$fips == "06059",]
SBCNEI <- form[form$fips =="06071",]

AllNEI<-rbind(rbind(LANEI,OCNEI), SBCNEI)

GetCounty <-function (fips)
{
  if (fips == "06037")
    return ("Los Angeles")
  else if (fips == "06059")
    return ("Orange County")
  if (fips == "06071")
    return ("San Bernardino County")

}
chckSolv <- function (SCC)
{

   if ( SCC$SCC.Level.One == "Solvent Utilization")
    return ("Yes")
  else
    return ("No")
}


CountyData <- sapply(AllNEI$fips, GetCounty)
solventData <- sapply(AllNEI$SCC,chckSolv)
AllNEI <-cbind (AllNEI, Solvent = solventData)
AllNEI <- cbind(AllNEI, county = CountyData)
```

Comment: What is the structure of `"Source_Classification_Code.rds"`?

Comment: I think the issue is that you are passing a single vector to your `chckSolv` function but it looks like it should take a dataframe with a column called `SCC.Level.One`. Try `solventData <- sapply(AllNEI,chckSolv)`

Comment: FYI you might consider a vectorized function such as `ifelse()` instead of your `chckSolv` and `GetCounty` functions. It would be faster and would accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the vectorized `ifelse()`. Your earlier error is due to referencing a named element, `SCC.Level.On` on a specific value, `SCC`.

```
AllNEI$CountyData <- ifelse(AllNEI$fips == "06037", "Los Angeles",
                            ifelse(AllNEI$fips == "06059", "Orange County", 
                                   ifelse(AllNEIfips == "06071", "San Bernardino County", NA)

AllNEI$SolventData <- ifelse(AllNEI$SCC == "Solvent Utilization", "Yes", "No")
```

Additionally, you can reduce rbind operations:

```
AllNEI <- NEI[NEI$fips %in% c("06037", "06059", "06071"), c("fips", "SCC", "Emissions")]
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears that you are using `SCC` as the argument name for you function `chckSolv`, but then using it to try to refer to the `SCC` Data Frame that is globally defined in your script. Your function won't use the globally defined version (since the name `SCC` is defined locally in your function)

If you change the argument to a different name it should work. Try something like this:

```
chckSolv <- function (vec)
{

   if ( vec == "Solvent Utilization")
     return ("Yes")
   else
     return ("No")
}
```

Comment: @MikeyMike That's true but to be more explicit and not confuse between his globally defined variables it's a good idea to change the argument name.